# UISearchBar not becoming first responder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar in an application. Initially, its at the bottom of a page, but I'd like to to move up. I was able to accomplish that, but I cannot make the keyboard appear now. I've tried the typical suggestions without avail. My code should be working.

iOS 8.

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    //move the search bar up to the correct location eg
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.4
                     animations:^{
                         searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(searchBar.frame.origin.x,
                                                      0,
                                                      searchBar.frame.size.width,
                                                      searchBar.frame.size.height);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [self.searchDisplayController setActive: YES animated: YES];
                         self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.hidden = NO;
                         [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];



                     }];
                       [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```